# Tail recursion Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, filter, tail-recursion

I need help with this tail recursion in Scala. I have the following method header:

```
def filter[A](list:List[A], filter: A => Boolean): List[A] =
```

I have to write the method body with tail recursion and a use a `cases` that match with `h::t` and `Nil` but I don't know how to do this with `Booleans`?

I have tried another example with counting a `List` in a tail-recursive style:

```
def sum(list:List[Int]):Int = {
     def sumRec(list: List[Int], acc:Int): Int = list match {
       case Nil => acc 
       case h::t => sumRec(t,acc+h)
     }
     sumRec(list,0)
}
```

@om-nom-nom Could you help me with one more recursion that I have to solve in Scala?
I need to map elements to their given length with recursion.
Here is the code that should be completed:

```
def map[A,B](list:List[A], operation:A=>B):List[B] =
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not going to provide you complete answer, but here is the tip: your second argument is a test function, which can be invoked for every item in your collection, in order to decide whether it should be dropped or not:

```
scala> def isOdd(x: Int) = x % 2 == 1
isOdd: (x: Int)Boolean

scala> val filter: Int => Boolean = isOdd
filter: Int => Boolean = <function1>

scala> filter(3)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> filter(4)
res1: Boolean = false
```

Given that you already nailed recursive sum and keeping in mind that accumulator can be of type List, this should be sufficient to solve your problem.